# JMeter plugin for generate parameters in HTML report specified in XSL template

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, jmeter

Does anybody know how to generate a HTML report in JMeter with some java template engine (XSLT, Xalan, etc.) working with specified XSL template?

The reason why I want to use a template engine is that I want in HTML report just parameters that I specified in XSL template (for example I want just a one graph for throughput in HTML report and no other graphs).

And if is possible without using CMD but using some a JAVA plugin as "Listener".

Thank you very lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that JMeter has a couple of XSL templates you can either use or re-use as a basis, they are located under "extras" folder of your JMeter installation, or if you obtained JMeter via some form of package manager you can get them from [JMeter source repositories](http://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html) at:

- [jmeter-results-report_21.xsl](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/jmeter-results-report_21.xsl)
- [jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl)
- [schematic.xsl](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/schematic.xsl)

The above XSL templates are called from the [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter), the [build.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/build.xml) Ant script can also be found under "extras" folder, check out **xslt-report** target to see how you can trigger the .jtl result file transformation.

You can also check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on "alternative" ways of running JMeter tests, it covers Ant and Maven plugins which both use XSLT transformation in order to produce the load report.